# Rails member path prefixes not updating after changing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was doing some refactoring of a Rails application and splitting a table into two. Doing this involves me renaming the original model and then adding a new one and migrating the data. I changed the route for a resource after renaming the table and model. It only updated the prefixes for some of the routes. What's going on here? This resource used to be called 'serves'. Here's the relevant routes:

```
resources :notices, only: %i[index edit update destroy] do
get 'close', on: :member
get 'cancel_or_close', on: :member
get 'new_lockout', on: :member
post 'create_lockout', on: :member
get 'new_five_days', on: :collection
post 'create_five_days', on: :collection
post 'batch_update', on: :collection
# This bit of nuttiness is to solve an issue regarding submitting the same form to multiple actions
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('create_pdfs'), action: 'create_pdfs'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('create_envelopes'), action: 'create_envelopes'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_canceled'), action: 'mark_canceled'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_processing'), action: 'mark_processing'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_filed'), action: 'mark_filed'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_out_for_service'), action: 'mark_out_for_service'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_service_complete'), action: 'mark_service_complete'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_reconciled'), action: 'mark_reconciled'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_closed'), action: 'mark_closed'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('mark_billed'), action: 'mark_billed'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('get_unbilled_csv'), action: 'get_unbilled_csv'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('export_serves_csv'), action: 'export_serves_csv'
post 'edit_multiple', on: :collection, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new('batch_edit'), action: 'batch_edit'
end
```

Here's the output of 'rake routes'

```
close_serve GET    /notices/:id/close(.:format)                                                             notices#close
    cancel_or_close_serve GET    /notices/:id/cancel_or_close(.:format)                                                   notices#cancel_or_close
        new_lockout_serve GET    /notices/:id/new_lockout(.:format)                                                       notices#new_lockout
     create_lockout_serve POST   /notices/:id/create_lockout(.:format)                                                    notices#create_lockout
    new_five_days_notices GET    /notices/new_five_days(.:format)                                                         notices#new_five_days
 create_five_days_notices POST   /notices/create_five_days(.:format)                                                      notices#create_five_days
     batch_update_notices POST   /notices/batch_update(.:format)                                                          notices#batch_update
    edit_multiple_notices POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#create_pdfs
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#create_envelopes
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_canceled
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_processing
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_filed
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_out_for_service
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_service_complete
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_reconciled
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_closed
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#mark_billed
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#get_unbilled_csv
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#export_serves_csv
                          POST   /notices/edit_multiple(.:format)                                                         notices#batch_edit
                  notices GET    /notices(.:format)                                                                       notices#index
               edit_serve GET    /notices/:id/edit(.:format)                                                              notices#edit
                    serve PATCH  /notices/:id(.:format)                                                                   notices#update
                          PUT    /notices/:id(.:format)                                                                   notices#update
                          DELETE /notices/:id(.:format)
```

As you can see, some of the routes have updated their prefixes properly, but others still maintain serves (member routes) in their prefix. Why is this happening?

EDIT:
Here's some of the model code:

```
class Notice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :affiant, optional: true
  before_save :set_date_of_service, :set_default_billing_status, :set_default_affiant

class Affiant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :zip_codes
  has_many :notices

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :properties
  has_many :notices
  has_many :documents
```

Comment: Add code of related models, please. Check if you renamed all files. Try to run `spring stop && rake routes | grep notices`

Comment: ^^ This. My guess is it's some sort of cacheing issue. Are you using `spring`? Or `zeus`? Or something odd with docker perhaps?

Comment: I've added the relation part of all of the model classes involved. I did a comp search of the project yesterday looking for references to the old name and I didn't spot any. I'm using Rubymine, so no spring/zeus or docker. I agree that it seems like some sort of caching issue, though bizarre that only the member routes, but not the collection routes get hit.

Comment: Not that using Rubymine precludes any of the above, just using the stock setup. Also, I killed and restarted the server, so I'm not sure where it would be getting cached.

Comment: I don't think your choice of IDE (rubymine) has any relevance to potential causes of cacheing (spring, zeus, docker, ...). What happens if you run **`bundle exec`** `rake routes`? When you say "I did a complete search of the project ... and didn't spot any", I can see at least *one* reference: `export_serves_csv`. Now this itself isn't the problem of course, but it does make me a little suspicious that you've missed something in your search. *For example*, maybe your project mounts a rails engine, and the reference is in another gem?

Comment: Does the database table still exist? What references are there to `serve` in `app/` or `lib/` or `config/` or `db/`? Did you run all database migrations? ... I'm really just guessing here, because I don't know how to reproduce the problem (although I realise that if *you* knew, you presumably wouldn't be asking this question ;))

Comment: The db table does not still exist. There are references to serve in app, but none of them should matter. Most of them are calls to what should be the defunct path helpers. Some of the controller methods are still left. I did the comp search and looked at each individual file to see if it should matter. Theoretically, the routes file should be completely agnostic to the contents of app/, lib/, or db/ provided I'm not calling routes.draw somewhere else, which I am not.

Comment: You're right and I'm dumb. I used the "smart refactor" in rubymine to do the refactor and it looks like it added an inflection from 'serve' to notices which is what was causing the issue. If you want to put that as the answer, I'll accept.